# could not connect to mysql because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: php, mysql

> `Warning: mysql_connect():` 
>   No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. in `D:\xampp\htdocs\ex\ctop.php` on line 22
>   Could not connect: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

**Code**

```
<html>

   <head>
      <title></title>
      <style type="text/css">
      body{background-image:url(img/11.jpg);
       background-size: 100% 100%;}
      table{font-size:20pt;
        color: Black;
      text-align: center;
font-weight:bold;}
th{color:       BC8F8F;}
      </style>
   </head>

   <body>
<?php
            $dbhost = 'localhost';
            $dbuser = 'corn';
            $dbpass = 'pword';

            $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

   if(! $conn ) {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

   $sql = 'SELECT Distinct i.Title,i.Singer,i.Mname  FROM items i, vote v
                   where i.Title=v.Title
                   group by v.Title
                   order by sum(v.rating) Desc';
   mysql_select_db('test_db');
   $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

   if(! $retval ) {
      die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
   }
    echo" <center>";
    echo "<h2>Based on ratings given by users!!</h2>";
    echo "<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>";
   echo "<table border=1>";
    echo" <tr>";

                    echo"<th>Title</th>";

                    echo"<th>Movie</th>";
                    echo"<th>Singer</th>";


               echo" </tr>";


   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval)) {

      echo "<tr>  <td>{$row['Title']} </td>".
           "<td>{$row['Mname']} </td>".
         "<td> {$row['Singer']}</td>  
           </tr>";
   }
    echo "</table>";
     echo "</center>";

   mysql_close($conn);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I have already executed this php program. But sometimes I get this warning, so I tried reinstalling MySQL then I got output. Now again same warning I'm getting, how to completely overcome this problem?

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated try to use mysqli_*

Comment: show your connection code

Comment: I'm getting same warning on using mysqli also

Comment: Have you checked your credentials for MySQL connection is right?, because mostly this error says you are accessing with wrong creadentials.

Comment: because **mysql_\*** is deprecated, use of **mysqli_\*** is suggested, it don't solve your problem.

Comment: Are you sure your MySQL server is actually running? Can you connect to the database using the command line or something like phpMyAdmin?

Comment: the database server probably isn't running. Either that or you have a firewall issue. There's lots online about this message already: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Mysql+No+connection+could+be+made+because+the+target+machine+actively+refused+it.&oq=Mysql+No+connection+could+be+made+because+the+target+machine+actively+refused+it.&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.1256j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and since everything looks just fine, the issue is in the server port. Try to specify the server port when you define your server $dbhost = 'localhost:(Server Port)';

Answer (score -1):

I'm sure your MySQL server isn't running. So my suggestion is to recheck your server status is online or not. if not then debug why it's not online. Hope this will solve your problem.

**Note: `mysql_` driver for connecting with database is insecure and can cause you big security issue in your application like SQL injection so please avoid using `mysql_` and use `PDO` this is a advanced driver for connecting with database**

Comment: The error **"because the target machine actively refused it"** means that the server is online, but you can not access the server with the credentials you've provided, or The IP address from which you're trying to connect is not allowed to connect.